# How To Add New Currency in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I'm making magento2 shop for my malawian client. I want to add new currency in magento2... "Malawian Kwacha" which is not listed in default currency list. How could i add new currency and work successfully. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to Stores > Configuration > General > Currency Setup
2. There are three options :

   **a. Base Currency** : That is base Currency for Store, Based on Which all currencies value will be converted if you have multiple currency Store.

   **b. Default Display Currency** : This is default currency which will be shown in frontend.

   **c. Allow Currencies** : This is for which if you want multiple currencies for you site.

**Important One :** 
***I found 'Malawian Kwacha' in all three options. See Image Added in Answer. If you can not find , Please upgrade to Latest Magento 2 Stable Version.***

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Did you get My answer @KamalPatel ??

Comment: Yes, got that by upgrading magento2 ... thank you for quick response! :)